# Show that "$\Gamma \models S \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash S$" entails "if $\Gamma \nvdash P \And \sim P$ then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, intuition

> Show that "$\Gamma \models S \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash S$" entails "if
>   $\Gamma \nvdash P \And \sim P$ then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable"

I'm primarily confused with the notation being used here. In particular, I understand that "satisfiable" means there is at least one interpretation that makes $\Gamma$ true, but I'm not sure what $\vdash$ means nor what the statement $\Gamma \models S \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash S$ means. The first part tells me that $\Gamma$ "makes true" $S$, or that there is no interpretation which makes $\Gamma$ true and $S$ false, but I don't understand how to interpret what comes after this (the "$\Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash S$" part). I'd really appreciate if someone could clear up this notation for me.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $\Gamma \models S$ should mean $S$ is satisfied in *all* models of $\Gamma$ and not just some.  Then it is saying if $S$ is true in all models of $\Gamma$ then actually $\Gamma$ proves $S$ (the turnstile is read as "proves").

Comment: This means (usually) there is a finite proof from the sentences of $\Gamma$ where the last line is $S$.

Comment: @RyanSullivant how do we make sense of the term "proves?" What does it mean for $\Gamma$ to "prove" $S$?

Comment: In general, it means what I just said (of course this depends on your system however). So there is a finite set of sentences $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n$ where either:
$\sigma_i \in \Gamma$ or $\sigma_i$ is a logical axiom or $\sigma_i$ follows from modus ponens from $\sigma_j, \sigma_k$ where $j <k < i$ 
and $\sigma_n$ is $S$.  Perhaps, someone else can explain it better though.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. It means that $S$ is derivable from $\Gamma$ using a proof that gets us from $\Gamma$ to $S$? So how can we show that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable? If you cannot derive a contradiction from  $\Gamma$, how does this show that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable? Also, one more point, what does the $\Rightarrow$ mean in this context?

Comment: For an example of the difference, in any group $G$ and elements $x,y$ it is true that $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$ so a group models  $(\forall x, y) (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$ (or that sentence is satisfied in any group).  On the other hand, using the group axioms, we can prove $(\forall x,y) (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$.

Comment: Actually, what my first comment was about is just the "$\Gamma \models S \implies \Gamma \vdash S$".  The $\implies$ means an implication that we would normally mean while talking.  For example, $4$ divides $k \implies k$ is even.  It is just to not confusing it with the logical connectives.  But then we have even one more implication in the form of the word $entails$, so there is a lot going on.  I would go about proving this by contradiction, so assume the stuff after "entails" is false and then prove $\Gamma \models S \implies \Gamma \vdash S$ is false.  I'll try and write an answer.

Comment: But yes, you are right, derivable is the same thing as how I say "proves". And I am not sure if there is a good way to show a general theory is satisfiable, since to do that you would have to come up with a set and show each sentence is true in it.  That's why I am thinking contradiction might be better in this case.

Comment: Note: what I said in the 2 comments ago at the end on how to prove that statement is not right, just see my answer.

Comment: @Ryan Sullivant - you are right: we can prove *satisfiability* of a set of sentences $\Gamma$ exibhiting a model for it, but in this case $\Gamma$ is "general"; we have no way to "know" nothing about the sentences in it ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yeah, thanks for the detailed explanation in your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think this is what we may want to do.  Suppose for contradiction that $\Gamma$ is not satisfiable.  This means that $\Gamma$ has no models.  Now, fix some sentence $P$ and let $S \equiv P \wedge \neg P$.  Now, $\Gamma \models S$ will be vacuously true since there are no models of $\Gamma$, (i.e. any model of $\Gamma$ will satisfy $S$).  So by the hypothesis, we have that $\Gamma \vdash S$.  But this means $\Gamma \vdash P \wedge \neg P$ contradicting the hypothesis that this does not happen.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol :

> $\Gamma \vDash S$

means that the sentence $S$ is a *logical consequence* of the set of sentences $\Gamma$.

This means, as said in the above comments :

> every interpretation that satisfies all sentences $\varphi \in \Gamma$ (i.e. is a *model* of $\Gamma$), satisfies also $S$.

The symbol :

> $\Gamma \vdash S$

means that the sentence $S$ is *provable* from the set of assumptions $\Gamma$.

This means that the problem implicitly assume that we have in place a *proof system*, made of (one or more) *rules of inference* and (zero o more) *axioms* and a definition of *derivation*; in this way, the symbol above is defined (as in the comment) as :

> there is a finite set of sentences $\sigma_1, … ,\sigma_n$, where either: *(i)* $\sigma_i \in \Gamma$, or *(ii)* $\sigma_i$ is a logical axiom or *(iii)* $\sigma_i$   follows by a *rule of inference* from some (one or more) $\sigma_k$, where $1 \le k < i$  and $\sigma_n = S$.

Finally, the symbol :

> $\Gamma \nvdash P \land \lnot P$

means that form $\Gamma$, with the proof system above, we can derive a *contradiction*, i.e. $\Gamma$ is *inconsistent*. So, we say that $\Gamma$ is *consistent* when it is **not** inconsistent (i.e.when we cannot derive a contradiction from it).

The statement of the problem boils down to :

> > show that if $\Gamma$ is *consistent*, then it is *satisfiable*.

Now, in order to prove it, procede as suggested by @Ryan Sullivant, i.e. by contradiction, and suppose that $\Gamma$ is not satisfiable. This means that $\Gamma$ has **no** models.

Now re-read the relation of *logical consequence* explained above : $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ iff every model of $\Gamma$ is also a model of $\varphi$.

But we assumed that $\Gamma$ has no models; so the last condition is vacuosly satisfied for every $\varphi$, and also for $P \land \lnot P$.

This means that, if $\Gamma$ is not *satisfiable*, i.e. if it has no models, than :

> $\Gamma \vDash P \land \lnot P$.

At this point, we need the theorem mentioned in the hypotheses of the problem :

> if $\Gamma \vDash S$, then $\Gamma \vdash S$

(if $S$ is a *logical conseuqnce* of $\Gamma$, then $S$ is *provable* from $\Gamma$; we say that the proof system is *complete*).

Having proved, form the assumption that $\Gamma$ is unstaisfiable, that $P \land \lnot P$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$, we use the above theorem to conclude that $P \land \lnot P$ is provable form $\Gamma$.

In conclusion :

> > if $\Gamma$ is *unsatisfiable*, then $\Gamma$ is *inconsistent*.

Answer (score 2):

$\Gamma \models S$ means 'Every model of $\Gamma$ satisfies wff $S$ ' So given statement can be written as follows:

> For all wff $S$ on the language of $\Gamma$, if every model of $\Gamma$ satisfies $S$ then $\Gamma$ proves $S$.

Formally, this statement is written as $\forall S[ (\forall \mathcal{M} :\mathcal{M}\models \Gamma \implies \mathcal{M}\models S)\implies \Gamma\vdash S]$. Take contraposition of this statement then we get

> For all wff $S$ on the language of $\Gamma$, if $\Gamma$ does not prove $S$ then there is a model of $\Gamma$ that does not satisfy $S$.

(Formally it is written as $\forall S [\Gamma \nvdash S \implies (\exists \mathcal{M} :\mathcal{M}\models\Gamma \,\&\, \mathcal{M}\not\models S)]$.)

Note that if $\mathcal{M}\not\models S$ then $\mathcal{M}\models(\lnot S)$. Take $S=P\land \lnot P$ then you get desired proposition.

Comment: Sorry ... $\Gamma \vDash S$ does **not** means "$S$ is *provable* form $\Gamma$", but instead : "$S$ is a *logical consequence* of $\Gamma$". If you do not define a proof system, and until you do not prove a soundness and completeness theorem, the two relations are not equivalent.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I do not say that $\Gamma\models S$ means '$\Gamma$ proves $S$'. I say that "$\Gamma\models S$ means 'every model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\Gamma$ satisfies $S$'."

Comment: @tetori I think Mauro is talking about the first line: you write "$\Gamma \models S$" but I think you mean "$\Gamma \models S \implies \Gamma \vdash S$"

Comment: @RyanSullivant Ah... I find problem in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am sorry for you that misunderstood your claim.

Comment: @tetori - you are welcome !